# PostgreSQL - migrate a query with 'start with' and 'connect by' in oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql, connect-by

I have the following query in oracle. I want to convert it to PostgreSQL form. Could someone help me out in this,

```
SELECT user_id, user_name, reports_to, position 
FROM   pr_operators
START WITH reports_to = 'dpercival'
CONNECT BY PRIOR user_id = reports_to;
```

Comment: You'll probably have to show some sample data, expected results, and/or table definitions. In general, look at `WITH RECURSIVE` and common table expressions.

Comment: What is your PostgreSQL version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A something like this should work for you ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6b9b6/2)):

```
WITH RECURSIVE q AS (
    SELECT po.user_id,po.user_name,po.reports_to,po.position
      FROM pr_operators po
     WHERE po.reports_to = 'dpercival'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT po.user_id,po.user_name,po.reports_to,po.position
      FROM pr_operators po
      JOIN q ON q.user_id=po.reports_to
)
SELECT * FROM q;
```

You can [read more on recursive CTE's in the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html).

**Note**: your design looks strange -- `reports_to` contains string literals, yet it is being comapred with `user_id` which typicaly is of type `integer`.

Comment: This query doesn't work. It is giving the following error 

ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"